# haskell parse error on the simple quicksort algorithm

Tags: haskell

I am a noob in haskell. I read the **real world haskell**  book, and wrote the following code as the standard example, but it is somehow wrong.

```
mquicksort::(Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mquicksort [] = []
mquicksort (x:xs) =
    let xsmall = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
          xbig = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x ]
    in xmall ++ [x] ++ xbig
```

GHCI says `"parse error on input '='"`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in these two lines:

```
let xsmall = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
      xbig = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x ]
```

The cause of the error is apparently a big source of confusion/problems in Haskell.  The point is that in Haskell, lines that are in the same block need to line up on the left.  So, `xsmall` and `xbig` should be lined up directly on top of one another.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation.

**Edit:** You also have a typo, writing `xmall` in last line where I guess you meant `xsmall`.

**Edit 2, for clarification:** The code you want is:

```
let xsmall = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
    xbig = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x ]
```

or

```
let xsmall = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
    xbig   = mquicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x ]
```

Comment: Ehh, I had thought that it is a good convention to align them by `=` operator. So sad.

Comment: @richard.g yea, well, you can still line up the equals symbols as in my second example.  I admit your original code might look a bit better.

Comment: You can also use explicit blocks with braces and semicolons instead of layout if you wish.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka <shudder/> Better to learn how layout works, and only once you're used to it, decide whether to use explicit braces and semicolons, thus making a decision on the basis of knowledge rather than ignorance.